# GDB is not showing line number information although debuginfo is installed

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb, opensuse, gcov

I am trying to debug `gcov` code. I wrote a simple C program which calls `__gcov_flush()` method which is part of gcc/gcov.

After confirming that  `libgcov.a` library has not been built with debug symbols, I have installed debuginfo packages for gcc on my machine (`SLES 10`).

```
# gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-suse-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-threads=posix --prefix=/usr --with-local-prefix=/usr/local --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran,obj-c++,java,ada --enable-checking=release --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.1.2 --enable-ssp --disable-libssp --disable-libgcj --with-slibdir=/lib64 --with-system-zlib --enable-shared --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libstdcxx-allocator=new --program-suffix= --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --without-system-libunwind --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-suse-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)


# rpm -qi gcc-debuginfo-4.1.2_20070115-0.29.6.x86_64
Name        : gcc-debuginfo                Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 4.1.2_20070115                    Vendor: SUSE LINUX Products GmbH, Nuernberg, Germany
Release     : 0.29.6                        Build Date: Sat Sep  5 03:04:50 2009
Install Date: Thu Apr 24 05:25:32 2014      Build Host: bingen
Group       : Development/Debug             Source RPM: gcc-4.1.2_20070115-0.29.6.src.rpm
Size        : 251823743                        License: GPL v2 or later
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Sat Sep  5 03:06:59 2009, Key ID a84edae89c800aca
Packager    : http://bugs.opensuse.org
URL         : http://gcc.gnu.org/
Summary     : Debug information for package gcc
Description :
This package provides debug information for package gcc.
Debug information is useful when developing applications that use this
package or when debugging this package.
Distribution: SUSE Linux Enterprise 10


/usr/lib/debug/usr/bin # ls -lrt gcov.debug
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 94216 Sep  5  2009 gcov.debug
```

However, even after installing the proper version of debuginfo (`gcov.debug`) packages, GDB still cannot recognize the line number information, it just passes the control to next line without reporting line number (or stepping into the function).

```
(gdb)s
26            i++;
(gdb)s
27            __gcov_flush();
(gdb)s
28            printf("%d",i);
(gdb)
(gdb) show debug-file-directory
The directory where separate debug symbols are searched for is "/usr/lib/debug".
```

Why GDB cannot identify line number information for gcov? If I have not installed the proper version of debuginfo packages for gcc/gcov, How to confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After confirming that  libgcov.a library has not been built with debug symbols, I have installed debuginfo packages

You don't appear to understand how debuginfo packages work. They can't magically add debuginfo to an archive library that was built without debug symbols (or one that was stripped).

The *usual* build flow is:

- build everything with `-g`
- prepare separate debuginfo packages for all *fully-linked* binaries (executables and shared libraries)
- strip *fully-linked* binaries (but not archive libraries)

This allows binaries and shared libraries to be small, but still debuggable after installing the debuginfo package.

Apparently, on SLES10 the "but not archive libraries" was not honored, and `libgcov.a` got stripped as well. Since separate debuginfo packages do not work for archive libraries, you can't get that info back. Your only option is to rebuild GCC from sources.

P.S. Why would they strip `libgcov.a`?

It's a trade-off: binaries that end-users link will be smaller, but code in `libgcov.a` will not be debuggable.

Since most end-users never debug `libgcov.a`, I'd say it was not an unreasonable trade-off.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Although it seems obvious, please clarify this: In case of static libraries, the debug symbols will matter on the machine where the executable is linked, not the machine where the exe is running, right? It doesn't matter if the machine has a static lib with debug symbols or not when the program is running.

Comment: @ernesto That is correct: an archive library is copied into the binary that is linked against it at static link (build) time. The archive library is not used at runtime *at all*, and need not be present.